# Como fazer uma tela de Login e senha utilizando JSF

Tags: java, aplicação-web

Fiz uma tela de login, nessa tela o usuário poderá se cadastrar através de um botão cadastro, feito o cadastro ele poderá acessar o sistema informando senha e CPF.

Meu sistema será para denúncias ambientais, e terá um fiscal que vai receber todas a denúncias feitas pelos usuários.

Minha duvida é, como vou fazer para que quando o usuário se logue, ele tenha acesso a tela do usuário, e quando o fiscal se logue vá para a tela fiscal?

Tela Login Bean:

```
package Bean;

import DAO.UsuarioDAO;
import Domain.Usuario;
import Util.MensagesUtil;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;



/**
 *
 * @author alexandre
 */

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private UsuarioDAO usuarioDao;
    private ArrayList<Usuario> itens;



    public String login() throws SQLException {
        usuarioDao = new UsuarioDAO();
         usuario = usuarioDao.obterUsuario(usuario);

         if (usuario != null) {
            return "/telaOpcaoUsuario.xhtml";
        }
         else {
             MensagesUtil.adicionarMensagemErro("Usuario e Senha invalidos !");
             return "/login.xhtml";
         }
    }

    public void Cadastrar() {
     try {
            usuarioDao = new UsuarioDAO();
            usuarioDao.salvar(usuario);

            setItens(usuarioDao.listar());
            MensagesUtil.adicionarMensagemSucesso("Usuario Salvo Com Sucesso");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            MensagesUtil.adicionarMensagemErro(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void Excluir() {
        try {
            usuarioDao = new UsuarioDAO();
            usuarioDao.excluir(usuario);

            setItens(usuarioDao.listar());
            MensagesUtil.adicionarMensagemSucesso("Usuario Removido com Sucesso");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            MensagesUtil.adicionarMensagemErro(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void Editar() {
        try {
            usuarioDao = new UsuarioDAO();
            usuarioDao.editar(usuario);

            setItens(usuarioDao.listar());
            MensagesUtil.adicionarMensagemSucesso("Usuario Editado Com Sucesso");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();;
            MensagesUtil.adicionarMensagemErro(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }


    public UsuarioDAO getUsuarioDao() {
        return usuarioDao;
    }

    public void setUsuarioDao(UsuarioDAO usuarioDao) {
        this.usuarioDao = usuarioDao;
    }

    public ArrayList<Usuario> getItens() {
        return itens;
    }

    public void setItens(ArrayList<Usuario> itens) {
        this.itens = itens;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
}
```

Tela LOGIN XHTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                template="/WEB-INF/template/layout.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="menu">

        <h:outputText value="Bem Vindo ao Sistema DMVA"/>
 </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="metadata"/> 

    <ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:body>

    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true" />  
        <h:form id="frm-login">
           <div align="center" >     
          <p:panelGrid  columns="1" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-12" >  
              <p:toolbar >
                <f:facet name="left" >
                    <h:outputText value="Faça Seu Login"  /> 
                </f:facet>                
              </p:toolbar> 

     <!-- PainelGroup Serve para unir os elementos em um coluna -->   
                <h:panelGroup> 
                    <p:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF" style="margin-left:17px; font-weight:bold"/>
                    <p:inputMask id="cpf" value="#{loginBean.usuario.cpf}" mask="999.999.999-99" />

                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup>
                     <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:password id="senha" maxlength="5" size="20" value="#{loginBean.usuario.senha}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{loginBean.login}" update="@form"/>
                <p:commandLink value="Cadastrar" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();" />      
         </p:panelGrid>
               </div>  
        </h:form>

    <p:dialog header="Cadastre Novo Usuário!!! " widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="bounce" height="100%" >
        <h:form id="frm-cadastro">        
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
        <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{loginBean.usuario.nome}"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="Endereco" value="Endereço" style="font-weight:bold"/>
         <p:inputText id="Endereco" value="#{loginBean.usuario.endereco}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <p:inputMask id="cpf" value="#{loginBean.usuario.cpf}" mask="999.999.999-99" />

        <h:outputLabel for="telefone" value="Telefone:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
         <p:inputMask id="telefone" value="#{loginBean.usuario.telefone}" mask="(99)-9999-9999" />

        <h:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha" style="font-weight:bold"/>
         <p:password id="Senha" value="#{loginBean.usuario.senha}" />


    </h:panelGrid>
         <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{loginBean.Cadastrar}" oncomplete="PF('dlg3').hide();" update="@form" />
    </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
  </h:body> 


     </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Deixe-me entender o caso de uso. Dependendo do tipo de usuário o redirecionamento pós login realizado é diferente, é isso? A tela de login é a mesma, mas dependendo do usuário, uma tela diferente irá aparecer?

Comment: isso, tem como fazer isso?  pois no sistema tem o fiscal que o ad cadastra, e tem o usuário(publico), dai o usuário se cadastra como usuário, não sei se fui claro

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará identificar o **perfil** dos usuários de alguma forma, uma vez que você esteja com os perfis definidos, basta trocar a página de direcionamento.

```
if (usuario != null) {
    if (usuario.getPerfil() == 1) {
        return "/telaFISCAL.xhtml";
    } else if (usuario.getPerfil == 2) {
        return "/telaNORMAL.xhtml";
    } else {
        return "/telaERRO.xhtml"
    }
}
```

Se você ainda não possuir nenhum tipo de perfil, talvez será necessário alterar o sistema de cadastro. Ou apenas adicionar a coluna na tabela e ir manualmente alterando todos os usuários no banco.

Coloquei os perfis como **1** e **2**, porque geralmente se faz relacionamentos de tabela, no caso a tabela de usuários não estaria escrito "fiscal" mas teria o ID do código de perfil, relacionando a tabela de usuários com a tabela de perfis, mas você também poderia ter o perfil fixo como texto direto na tabela de usuários, então o if ficaria mais ou menos `if ("FISCAL".equals(usuario.getPerfil())) {}`